# Creating use and assigning him license

Tags: userlicense, salesfoce

First of all the exact question:
Create a user and assign him a service cloud license
I decided to search on my own and here is what I found: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console2_assign_service_feature_license.htm&type=5
I was following to their guide but at the end when I need to choose the license I can't find that service cloud license.
[image]

what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

to assign service cloud license, you have to check  service cloud user field on user.

please refer to help doc:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console2_assign_service_feature_license.htm&type=5

Comment: Is it correct that i need to check that Service cloud user checkbox before I will be able to that service cloud license and if yes then how do I set that checkbox because at the moment it's inactive for me
https://prnt.sc/w5wx6g

Comment: to see that service cloud license*
I forgot to add see between to and that this may seem a little bit confusing

Comment: Service cloud user is only requirement for service cloud license. In license dropdown you can select salesforce/salesforce platform as per requirement.

Comment: I can't set that checkbox for some reason here is screenshot :  prnt.sc/w5wx6g

Comment: fill other information first like license  salesforce  select profile  first name last name email. it will be enabled after license selection if you have remaining license

Comment: Here is what i did, but still can't see that service cloud license in the user license dropdown list
https://prnt.sc/w5y8da

Comment: what you did is just right for service cloud license.  as i mentioned earlier, you dont need to select service cloud under license dropdown  as it will be salesforce only  which you already selected.   you just have to enable checkbox  which you did. you should have now access to service console.